# How much credit to give individual treatments from overall result?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, interaction, causality

I need to solve a tricky problem:

I have a dataset which has revenue lift data coming from 3 treatments. How do I attribute success to each treatment?

For example, we have a total revenue lift of 10%. This includes Treatment 1 + 2 + 3. How do I know how much credit Treatment 1, 2, and 3 individually get, causally speaking?

Any approach hint would be great as I do not know which method to start with.

Comment: For this to be answerable you need to tell us more. From what you have given, we can only guess

Comment: Are treatments 1,2,3 can be given at any combination ({1}, {2}, {3}, {1,3},...)? or do they accumulate ({1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3})? What's the control (1+2+3 give 10% more relative to what)?